# handle form request with ajax in django

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

i have problem with ajax when i send a request from my form it doesn't get the value from the form

this is my view code

```
def create(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        msg_text = request.POST.get('the_massage')
        data = {}
        form = ChatApp(message=msg_text, user=request.user)
        form.save()
        data['message']=form.message
        data['user']=form.user.username
        return JsonResponse(data)
    else:
        return JsonResponse({'nothing coming thrue'})
```

it shod get the_massage variable but it give me null value

this is my ajax function :

```
    $(function () {


  $('#main-form').on("submit"  ,function () {
    console.log("create function is here");
    var form = $(this);
    $.ajax({
      url: form.attr('action'),
      type: form.attr('method'),
      data: {the_massage:$('#msgbox').val()},
      dataType: 'json',

      success: function(json) {

        console.log(json);
        console.log('success');
      },
      error: function(error){
        console.log('we have error');
      },
    });
  });

});
```

when i console log the value it just come through in the console
please help me
and show me this in the console :

> Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type
>   application/json: "http://localhost:8000/create/".

Comment: 1st of all ur way of writing url is wrong in ajax : url : '/create',

Comment: the url not wrong its work just fine but the data not coming through

Comment: @MhadiAhmed what `Charlizard` meant is it is not a good practice to hard code url.

Comment: i have edit it still the same

Comment: until your url isn't correct it wont hit the ajax function at all .. then it came part of data not coming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the write answer : i solve this and its on git hub now https://github.com/mhadiahmed/tinypice

Answer (score 0):

Call the function in your event:

```
$('#main-form').on("submit"  ,function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log('submited');
    console.log($('#msgbox').val())
    created(); 
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I see many possibles problems here.

1) just for dev propose, delete `@login_required` (if you have) from your view and add `@csrf_exempt` to avoid this problem on dev.

2) Please look inside `request.body` on your view.

3) if point 1 and 2 doesn't work, please put the server response of this call: `POST localhost:8000/create 403 (Forbidden)`

Comment: now i have this error in the console : jquery-3.1.1.min.js:4 POST http://localhost:8000/create/ 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: but, what is the server response?
this line is an error `return JsonResponse({'nothing coming thrue'})`